# Create variable for path to application

Tags: linux, python, variable

In Linux, I type:

`/home/vincent/anaconda3/bin/python` :
this does go to the python shell, no problem.

Now if I try to create a variable for that link such as: 
`PYTHONEXEC=/home/vincent/anaconda3/bin/python`
If I type `PYTHONEXEC` I receive `command not found`.

This is to create a variable in a crontab, but it also doesn't work when used in the shell.

Comment: variables usually need `$PYTHONEXEC` to be interpolated, which exactly `PYTHONEXEC` lacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simplest solution here is to tell your shell to *expand* the PYTHONEXEC variable before running it; you do that by prefixing a `$`, as thrig commented:

```
$PYTHONEXEC
```

If you are going to use that syntax in a crontab entry, you'll need to source a file that defines the variable before using it.